# CakePHP Subdomain Cookies

Tags: php, cakephp, cookies, cakephp-1.3, subdomain

I'm trying to make a user session in CakePHP persist across all subdomains. All subdomains point back to the same Cake app and are routed to their respective controllers. for example, profile.example.com points to example.com/players/view. But for some reason, i cannot get the sessions to persist. I tried using the Cookie component, but id did absolutely nothing. Then i tried using ini_set in my bootstrap and at least got the correct cookie. however, it creates a seperate cookie when accessing the different subdomain. How exactly am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

putting this in my bootstrap fixed it:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.domain.com');
```

Don't know why it didn't work before, but it ended up working. Maybe clearing the cache did it.

Answer (score 0):

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1281/Controller-Setup

check the key $domain